# How can I Use PutcassandraRecord

Tags: apache-nifi

The goal is to be able to extend to several servers, in order to collect the files in a parallel way to count the number of lines and the number of files to store in a database each day.the type of data contained in the data file

|226789|23-Feb-1996|1995|0|1|1|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

|226780|08-Mar-1996|1996|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

|222507|01-Jan-1995|1995|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

|22308|01-Jan-1995|1995|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0

|222707|01-Jan-1995|1995|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0

I collect files I count the number of files and the number of lines in the files. I want to store these values in a database. I installed apache cassandra and created a database and a table. when I insert the number of lines and documents, I check my table and I don't see any data.
GetFile-->MergeContent-->CountText-->ReplaceText-->PutCassandraRecord.
The processors that make up the nifi flowfile I set up.
[image: nifi flowfile processors]

the PutCassandraRecord processor configuration
[image]

Comment: ListFile & FetchFile should be used instead of GetFile. Any errors in PutCassandraRecord?

Comment: Hi Sdairs, I have no error but when I count and put the number of files and the number of lines in PutCassandraRecord. I can't see anything in the database.

Comment: Can you update your question with a screenshot of the PutCassandraRecord config and an example of the FlowFile content before it goes in to it?